# FabricJS: The Bounding box of a path not get update when I change path coordinates

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

We have a problem working with paths in fabric, we need to change all the time the coordinates of a quadratic line (path) when the user drags the first point or the last point, the paths gets updated as usual, but the problem is that the bounding box of the path don't get update on every change of the object.path (see the image)

[image]

```js
(function() {
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

  canvas.on({
    'object:selected': onObjectSelected,
    'object:moving': onObjectMoving,
    'before:selection:cleared': onBeforeSelectionCleared
  });

  (function drawQuadratic() {

    var line = new fabric.Path('M 65 0 Q 100, 100, 200, 0', { fill: '', stroke: 'black' });

    line.path[0][1] = 100;
    line.path[0][2] = 100;

    line.path[1][1] = 200;
    line.path[1][2] = 200;

    line.path[1][3] = 300;
    line.path[1][4] = 100;

    line.selectable = true;
    line.hasControls = false;
    canvas.add(line);

    var p1 = makeCurvePoint(200, 200, null, line, null)
    p1.name = "p1";
    canvas.add(p1);

    var p0 = makeCurveCircle(100, 100, line, p1, null);
    p0.name = "p0";
    canvas.add(p0);

    var p2 = makeCurveCircle(300, 100, null, p1, line);
    p2.name = "p2";
    canvas.add(p2);

  })();

  function makeCurveCircle(left, top, line1, line2, line3) {
    var c = new fabric.Circle({
      left: left,
      top: top,
      strokeWidth: 5,
      radius: 12,
      fill: '#fff',
      stroke: '#666'
    });

    c.hasBorders = c.hasControls = false;

    c.line1 = line1;
    c.line2 = line2;
    c.line3 = line3;

    return c;
  }

  function makeCurvePoint(left, top, line1, line2, line3) {
    var c = new fabric.Circle({
      left: left,
      top: top,
      strokeWidth: 8,
      radius: 14,
      fill: '#fff',
      stroke: '#666'
    });

    c.hasBorders = c.hasControls = false;

    c.line1 = line1;
    c.line2 = line2;
    c.line3 = line3;

    return c;
  }

  function onObjectSelected(e) {
    var activeObject = e.target;

    if (activeObject.name == "p0" || activeObject.name == "p2") {
      activeObject.line2.animate('opacity', '1', {
        duration: 200,
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
      });
      activeObject.line2.selectable = true;
    }
  }

  function onBeforeSelectionCleared(e) {
    var activeObject = e.target;
    if (activeObject.name == "p0" || activeObject.name == "p2") {
      activeObject.line2.animate('opacity', '0', {
        duration: 200,
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
      });
      activeObject.line2.selectable = false;
    }
    else if (activeObject.name == "p1") {
      activeObject.animate('opacity', '0', {
        duration: 200,
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
      });
      activeObject.selectable = false;
    }
  }

  function onObjectMoving(e) {
    if (e.target.name == "p0" || e.target.name == "p2") {
      var p = e.target;

      if (p.line1) {
        p.line1.path[0][1] = p.left;
        p.line1.path[0][2] = p.top;
      }
      else if (p.line3) {
        p.line3.path[1][3] = p.left;
        p.line3.path[1][4] = p.top;
      }
    }
    else if (e.target.name == "p1") {
      var p = e.target;

      if (p.line2) {
        p.line2.path[1][1] = p.left;
        p.line2.path[1][2] = p.top;
      }
    }
    else if (e.target.name == "p0" || e.target.name == "p2") {
      var p = e.target;

      p.line1 && p.line1.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top });
      p.line2 && p.line2.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
      p.line3 && p.line3.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
      p.line4 && p.line4.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

(see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davidtorroija/uyLx3r41/1/)

There is a function to update the bounding box? or is this a bug in fabricjs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just hint in the good direction.
The line is re initialized every redrawn ( you can better do at mouse up ).
In this way the bounding box stays fit to the shape.

http://jsfiddle.net/uyLx3r41/2/

```js
(function() {
  var line;
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

  canvas.on({
'object:moving': onObjectMoving,
  });

  (function drawQuadratic() {

line = new fabric.Path('M 65 0 Q 100, 100, 200, 0', { fill: '', stroke: 'black' });

line.path[0][1] = 100;
line.path[0][2] = 100;

line.path[1][1] = 200;
line.path[1][2] = 200;

line.path[1][3] = 300;
line.path[1][4] = 100;

line.selectable = true;
line.hasControls = false;
canvas.add(line);

var p1 = makeCurvePoint(200, 200, null, line, null)
p1.name = "p1";
canvas.add(p1);

var p0 = makeCurveCircle(100, 100, line, p1, null);
p0.name = "p0";
canvas.add(p0);

var p2 = makeCurveCircle(300, 100, null, p1, line);
p2.name = "p2";
canvas.add(p2);

  })();

  function makeCurveCircle(left, top, line1, line2, line3) {
var c = new fabric.Circle({
  left: left,
  top: top,
  strokeWidth: 5,
  radius: 12,
  fill: '#fff',
  stroke: '#666'
});

c.hasBorders = c.hasControls = false;

c.line1 = line1;
c.line2 = line2;
c.line3 = line3;

return c;
  }

  function makeCurvePoint(left, top, line1, line2, line3) {
var c = new fabric.Circle({
  left: left,
  top: top,
  strokeWidth: 8,
  radius: 14,
  fill: '#fff',
  stroke: '#666'
});

c.hasBorders = c.hasControls = false;

c.line1 = line1;
c.line2 = line2;
c.line3 = line3;

return c;
  }


  function onObjectMoving(e) {
var p = e.target;
if (p.name == "p0" || p.name == "p2") {
  if (p.line1) {
    p.line1.path[0][1] = p.left;
    p.line1.path[0][2] = p.top;
  }
  else if (p.line3) {
    p.line3.path[1][3] = p.left;
    p.line3.path[1][4] = p.top;
  }
}
else if (p.name == "p1") {
  if (p.line2) {
    p.line2.path[1][1] = p.left;
    p.line2.path[1][2] = p.top;
  }
}
else if (p.name == "p0" || p.name == "p2") {
  p.line1 && p.line1.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top });
  p.line2 && p.line2.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
  p.line3 && p.line3.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
  p.line4 && p.line4.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
}
p && reinit();
  }
  
  function reinit() {
canvas.remove(line);
line = new fabric.Path(line.path, { fill: '', stroke: 'black' });
canvas.add(line);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.7/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks!, We just did the same as a hack, we remove from the canvas and then re add like you, so we can conclude that there is no way to re-set the bounding box manually without remove the element from the canvas?

Comment: No, actually you have to recreate the path, or at least execute same code of path creation from library. It is noticed and it is a feature we will implement.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to avoid, copying the object and re-inserting it. There should be some method that updates the bounding box for you.

Comment: In the new versions a lot of stuf has been added for this.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi tell please, is some feature already implemented to solve this problem? I use the last version of the library I have now the same problem

Comment: Hi @AntonAntonoff , there are a bunch of methods to help out. I need to dig them out i don't know by memory. Is not automatic anyway

Comment: you can use `Path._setPath` that is listed here:  https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/src/shapes/path.class.js#L62

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi sorry I don't understand how to use _setPath. Are there some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Follwing works with https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/6.0.0-rc.1/fabric.js

```
   const { left, top } = path1;
    path1._setPath(newPath);
    path1.set({ left, top });
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
```