# Bounding box of a fabric Path doesn't move after path's coordinates changed

Tags: fabricjs

I create a Rect and a Path. When the Rect is dragged, the Path moves after it.
After the coordinates of the Path have changed, the bounding box is in the same position.

[image]

There was a [similar topic 6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436344/fabricjs-the-bounding-box-of-a-path-not-get-update-when-i-change-path-coordinat). Maybe someone has already found a solution or there is a new method in the library?

P.S.: I tried to remove and add the path, but the bounding box is still the same.

```
var pathLine = new fabric.Path('M 10 10 L 10 100 L 100 100', {
    fill: '',
    stroke: 'black',
    objectCaching: false
})

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: 'grey',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
});

function createCanvas(id){
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas(id);

    canvas.add(pathLine);
    canvas.add(rect);
    pathLine.perPixelTargetFind = true;

    canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
        rect.setCoords();
        canvas.remove(pathLine);
        canvas.add(pathLine);

        pathLine.path[2][1] = rect.left ;
        pathLine.path[2][2] = rect.top ;

        canvas.renderAll();
    });

    return canvas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setCoords`

Checout the gotchas section https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/Fabric-gotchas